# bootstrap displays as if it is no jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-ui

I am building a project using jQuery bootstrap. All html static bootstrap works absolutely perfect. But jQuery part doesn't works. 
Console thinks, that  Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery.
But I think differently, because I added jQuery.

My code:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">

<script src = "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src = "js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

All paths in this file are added correctly. I had automatically added them on my Brackets.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: You need to add `js/jquery-3.2.1.js` before `bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 1):

You need to load jQuery before bootstrap because bootstrap javascript needs jquery to initiate